# I can't recieve an object in Navigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am new in learning react native and trying to send an object when user clicked on Flatlist row to display the product in the ProductDetail.tsx but i got an error "undefined is not a function" ...
I defined the navigation on App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import ProductDetail from './ProductDetails';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';


import {
  Colors,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';


function App(): JSX.Element {
 
  const Stack = createStackNavigator()
 
  const MyStack = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
             screenOptions={{
            
          }}
>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home} 
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
             <Stack.Screen name="ProductDetail" component={ProductDetail}  
             options={{title: 'Product Detail'}}
             />

        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  return (
     <MyStack />
  );
}


export default App;
```

And here is the Home.tsx code

```
function Home(): JSX.Element {


  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [shops, setShops] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const nav = useNavigation()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setShops(result.products);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
  
  return (
    
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
     <Text style = {styles.highlight}>Techno Shop</Text>
     <ShopList 
     shops={shops}
     navigation={nav}
     />

      
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

The ShopList.tsx Code

interface ShopListProps {
shops: any[];
navigation:any
}

```
class ShopList extends Component<ShopListProps> {

    
      render() {
        const { shops } = this.props;
        const nav = this.props.navigation;

        return (
    
            <FlatList
              data = {
                shops
              }
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
                 <ShopListRow 
                  shop={item} 
                  index={index} 
                  navigation={nav}
              
                />        
    
              }
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              initialNumToRender={16}
              extraData={this.state}
            />

    
         
        );
      }
}

export default ShopList;
```

From the ShopListRow.js i should navigate to ProductDetails.tsx with the product object
and here is the code of ShopListRow.js

```
export default class ShopListRow extends Component {
  infoPressed = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail', {
      shop: this.props.place
    })
  }
  
    render() {

        const {
          shop,
          index
        } = this.props

        return (
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.infoPressed}>
          <View key={shop.id} style={{ backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? '#D3E3EA' : '#B3E3DA' }}>
    
            <View style={styles.row}>
              
              <View style={styles.edges}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{shop.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{shop.description}</Text>

              </View>
    
              <View >
                
                <View 
                  style={styles.button}
                  
                >

                 <Image source={{uri: shop.thumbnail}} Image style={{ margin: 5, height: 120, width: 120 }} />

                </View>
    
    
              </View>
            </View>
    
          </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )
      }
}
```

and the code of ProductDetails.tsx where i got the error

```
interface PropsNav {
 // navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>
 navigation:any
}

  //function ProductDetail(): JSX.Element {
    export default class ProductDetail extends Component<PropsNav> {


      render(){
         
       const navigation = this.props.navigation;
       var shop = navigation.getParam('shop');
         return (
 
             <View  style={{ backgroundColor: '#D3E3EA' ,flex : 1}}>
                 
               <Text>{shop}</Text>
             </View>
         )
     }
 
   }

 // export default ProductDetail;
```

Thanks...

Comment: Try upload your code in Expo Snack